# Scrapy fila queue e mysql store

Tags: python, scrapy

Eu agrupei 2 perguntas, pois acho que são relacionadas.

Eu fiz um *script test*, onde salvo no banco os links salvos com seus dados.

**Esta é uma prática ruim?** **(Prioridade alta)**

Preciso realizar algo a mais para que não importe duplicados? No meu *pipeline* tem uma verificação simples procurando por `link=%s`, seria melhor eu usar md5 (link)? Consulta mais rápida?

Eu posso utilizar o `-s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1` para pausar e voltar o crawler, mas gostaria de saber como realizar isto por lista de links a serem processados no MySQL. **(Prioridade baixa)**

Eu preciso adicionar novos itens na minha lista de `start_urls`, ou queue, de forma dinâmica. 
**Devo criar `Request` com *callback* `parse_category`? Possui alguma forma de eu adicionar `self.queue` ou `self.start_url` e adicionar novas url's para serem processadas?** **(Prioridade alta)**

Comment: Luiz, bem vindo ao SOpt. Acesse a Ajuda e faça o Tour, para entender melhor como usar os recursos daqui.

Answer (score 0):

> Esta é uma prática ruim?

Não, considerando que a responsabilidade sobre lidar com a conexão MySQL esteja também sendo feita usando boas práticas em Python.

> Eu posso utilizar o `-s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1` para pausar e voltar o *crawler*, mas gostaria de saber como realizar isto por lista de links a serem processados no MySQL.

Primeiro você seleciona os registros do MySQL. Depois pode usar algum laço de repetição para ir chamando requisições e seus respectivos *callbacks*:

```
for registro in registros:
    resultado = Request(url=self.registro['url'], callback=self.meu_callback)
    # Aqui você faz operações adicionais com resultado, se precisar.
```

> Devo criar `Request` com *callback* `parse_category`?

É o correto a se fazer.

> Possui alguma forma de eu adicionar `self.queue` ou `self.start_url` e adicionar novas url's para serem processadas?

`self.queue` você irá trazer do seu banco de dados. `self.start_url` será a coluna de cada registro trazido.

Comment: vlw, sobre a última questão. Eu tentei algo como self.start_url.append(url) gerou erro. Eu devo realizar o append no banco e depois buscar. Seria isto? Existe alguma forma deu realizar isto de forma direta, em loops enquanto coleta itens por exemplo. Algo que eu possa executar em qualquer lugar do código. Mas no futuro vou resgatar do banco sim, apenas para agilizar por agora.. Vlw

Comment: Primeiro você vai ao banco e traz os dados. Depois passa esses dados para o *loop*.

Comment: Mas no caso deu usar um spider sem banco, algo mais prático que digo.

Comment: Não entendi. O que seria mais prático que um banco de dados?

Comment: Digo, se crio um spider pra test, as vezes quero rodar sem importar nada. Mas para isto eu precisava fazer um start_url.append(url). Isto acredito que deva ser feito por lógica distribuindo parse_start, parse_cat, parse_item. Mas minha duvida é se tem alguma função que modifique o start_url, ou incremente o queue. Vi algo com schedule.py, mas estou vendo pra evitar request duplicado. Talvez seja nele. n tenho certeza.

Comment: Melhor você colocar o código na sua pergunta, porque eu não entendi nada.

Comment: Sem problemas, eh que esta pergunta no comentário foi sem ser relacionado ao mysql.. Mas obrigado pela respostas.. Vlw mto..

Comment: Aproveitando, [veja aqui como o site funciona](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Obrigado!